# Take Excel cell content and place it into a formatted .txt file

Tags: vba, excel, powershell, formatted

So I have an Excel document, which is essentially a table.

For the purposes of this, we will use this:
[Dummy Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMwlq.jpg)

What I'm wanting to do is take the values from these cells and place them into a .txt file. However the text file has some required formatting, and follows a pattern per 'entry' (row) of the spreadsheet.

E.g.

```
***********
**THIS IS A FANCY TEXT FILE**
***********
<Start of entry text>
Predefined text here (Entry 1): $A1
Predefined text here:           $B1,$C1
Predefined text here:           $D1,$E1,$F1
Predefined text here: $G1,$H1
Predefined text here: $I1
Predefined text here: $J1,$K1,$L1
Predefined text here: $M1,$N1
<End of entry text>

<Start of entry text>
"As Above"
<End of entry text>
etc, etc
```

Also, if possible it would be beneficial to have all the values lined together.
ie. 
Like the first three lines are, as opposed to the last 4.

I'd like to be able to run a script that will then output a .txt file with some predefined data, followed by the relevant values of the cells for each entry in the table. I'm assuming I'll need some kind of 'For Each' loop, and I'll have to define the many variables, I'm just not really a coder by nature, and only dabble when I absolutely have to.

Thanks so much in advance for any help you can give.

I'm assuming VBA might be the most popular option, although I'm open to a potential powershell solution as well.

- XViper

---

Ok, so I've looked into some powershell options and think I would like to take that approach.

I've managed to get it working using an Import-XLS Function. However I'm not sure how to get the output to a .txt file.

```
Import-XLS '.\DummyData.xlsx' | Foreach-Object{
Write-host "Predefined data:" `t $_."Value 1"
Write-host "Predata:" `t`t`t $_."Value 2"
```

Which gives me this.

```
Predefined data:     AA
Predata:             11
Predefined data:     BB
Predata:             BB11
Predefined data:     CC
Predata:             CC11
Predefined data:     DD
Predata:             DD11
Predefined data:     EE
Predata:             EE11
Predefined data:     FF
Predata:             FF11
Predefined data:     GG
Predata:             GG11
Predefined data:     HH
Predata:             HH11
```

I know I can't use Write-Host to output, but how can I 'collect' all that data, and then have it output 'ForEach' to a .txt at the end?

Can I output it all collectively? or do I need to output each line one at a time?

Thanks!

---

Ok... so I've tried some more stuff.

```
$OutFile = ".\OutTest$(get-date -Format dd-MM).txt"

$Content = Import-XLS '.\DummyData.xlsx'

$Content | foreach-object{
Write-Output "Text1" $_."Value 1"
Write-Output "Text2" $_."Value 2"

} | Out-File $OutFile
```

So this appears to work, however the problem is, everything is on a new line now.

So I get this:

```
Text1
AA
Text2
11
Text1
BB
Text2
BB11
```

I need to be able to format/layout the text like I am able to using Write-Host.
Is this possible?

"Value 1" NEEDS to be on the same line as "Text1"

I may also need to do

"Text1: $Value1, $Value2, $Value3" on some lines.

Thanks again!

Comment: So, what did you already tried? Where do you encounter problems, so we can help you?

Comment: Hey Martin,

I admittedly haven't done very much, as I'm not too sure where to start.
I was hoping someone would be able to give me something generic to work with possibly that I could then try to build on from there.

My coding knowledge is admittedly limited. I just finished getting all that data OUT of the .txt file, which I did more or less manually.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: OK, you can do this in VBA. Try to find some examples of how to go through the cells on one side and how to output to a text file in VBA on the other hand.

Comment: Also, .xlx or .xlxs format? As they are internally very different formats.

Comment: The data can likely be in either format. Whichever you think would be easier to handle? Also just to clarify, this is not homework. It's more of a personal project I'm working on to help someone out. I'm well past my school & study years. :P

Comment: I've edited the top post with something I'm trying in Powershell.

Thanks again for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format your line as desired using [Windows PowerShell **-f** Format operator](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_-f_format.htm), see *about_Operators* help topic, e.g. `Get-Help 'about_Operators' -ShowWindow`:

> ```
> -f Format operator
>       Formats strings by using the format method of string 
>       objects. Enter the format string on the left side of the operator 
>       and the objects to be formatted on the right side of the operator.
>
>
>          C:\PS> "{0} {1,-10} {2:N}" -f 1,"hello",[math]::pi
>          1 hello      3.14
> ```
>
> For more information, see the [`String.Format` method](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=166450) and [Composite Formatting](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=166451).

Example:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { Write-Output $("{0},{1}" -f "Text1", $_."Name") }
###                                                       ↑
```

Sample output:

```
Text1,Downloaded
Text1,SF
Text1,SO
Text1,SU
Text1,addF7.ps1
```

**Edit** to answer extending question: *So, how would I go about writing my code so as to exclude writing the Output for Null values?* You could use [`Split(Char(), StringSplitOptions)` form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) of [`String.Split` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) from .NET framework and join the result back into a single string as follows (although maybe there are *smarter* straightforward methods):

```
$strng = "{0}:{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}" -f "Item x", 1, $null, 3, $null, $null
$strng
$strng.Split(",",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -join ","
```

**Output**

```
Item x:1,,3,,
Item x:1,3
```

Comment: Thanks!

Could you explain how that is working?

So {0} & {1} are determining the columns?
How would you apply a 'space' after the comma?

Comment: _How would you apply a 'space' after the comma?_ `$("{0}, {1}" -f "Text1", $_."Name")` @XViper please read the link in answer for detailed explanation and extended examples. Related although off-topic: [Write-Host Considered Harmful](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/)

Comment: Thanks JosefZ.
I actually remember seeing that article somewhere in my travels! (although I didn't read the whole thing).

Comment: How would I go about modifying the script to not output a line or comma if the cell value is null? So if "name" for row 2 was null, then it shouldn't write "Text1: $name". Thanks!

Comment: @XViper sorry I cannot test your `Import-XLS` function; however, if `$Content.Gettype()` returns something like `System.Array` then you could see all column headers (even null/empty ones) by typing e.g. `$Content[0]`. (Supposing that `$Content[0].GetType()` returns something like `PSCustomObject` and `System.Object`).

Comment: Hey JosefZ

Thanks for replying again.
This is the Import-XLS I used.
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/17bcabe7-322a-43d3-9a27-f3f96618c74b

Your assumptions were spot on.

BaseType is `System.Array`
`$Content[0].GetType()` returns `PSCustomObject` and `System.Object`

So, how would I go about writing my code so as to exclude writing the Output for Null values?

E.g. 
Item 1: 1, 2, 3, $null, $null

I would like it to output as

`Item 1: 1, 2, 3`

Not

`Item 1: 1, 2, 3,  , `

Thanks! :)

Comment: Alternatively if I could comment ; out the line if there are null values, that will work too. So if it Item 1: $null, then Write-Output ;Item 1:. What I'm trying to do falls over if it tries to reference a blank field, but not all items have the field. I'm just not sure how to include IF statements within the context of the csv output I'm given. I can include additional reference cells/fields in the Excel to use if that would help?

Comment: Please avoid extending your question topic repeatedly; ask another question instead of quizzing additional supplementary ones... If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.

Comment: No worries JosefZ. Will do.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I've solved it. (Although I'm not entirely sure how it works).

Through a bunch of trial and error and some fancy use of $() <-- Can someone explain this to me please?

I've come up with this.

```
$OutFile = ".\OutTest$(get-date -Format dd-MM).txt"

$Content = Import-XLS '.\DummyData.xlsx'

$Content | foreach-object{
Write-Output "Text1: `t $(($_).Value1)"
Write-Output "Text2: `t $(($_).Value2), $(($_)."Value 3")"  #I tried putting this all inside one $(), but that made the comma not appear. Why??

} | Out-File $OutFile
```

Which produces this:

```
Text1:   AA
Text2:   11, 22
Text1:   BB
Text2:   BB11, BB22
Text1:   CC
Text2:   CC11, CC22
Text1:   DD
Text2:   DD11, DD22
```

If there is a more elegant or better way of accomplishing this, please let me know. I think I've managed to accomplish what I need for this particular case.

I hope this helps someone later on! :)

I'd still appreciate any expert feedback.

Thanks.