# Alter output using exported Excel/CSV data if null values are found within 'foreach'

Tags: excel, csv, powershell, null, output

Sorry I wasn't quite sure how to word the question.

This is a follow-on from a previous question here: [Take Excel cell content and place it into a formatted .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159206/take-excel-cell-content-and-place-it-into-a-formatted-txt-file)

The Import-XLS function I'm using is from here:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/17bcabe7-322a-43d3-9a27-f3f96618c74b

My current code looks like this:

```
. .\Import-XLS.ps1

$OutFile = ".\OutTest$(get-date -Format dd-MM).txt"

$Content = Import-XLS '.\DummyData.xlsx'

$Content | foreach-object{

$field1 = $("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}" -f "Field1", $_."Value1", $_."Value2", $_."Value3", $_."Value4", $_."Value5", $_."Value6")
$field1.Split(",",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -join ","

$field2 = $("{0},{1}" -f "Field2", $_."Value1")
$field2.Split(",",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -join ","

} | Out-File $OutFile
```

My Dummydata is essentially this (I've inserted $null to point out the blank values)

```
Entries Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  Value6  Value7  Value8
Entry 1 1   2   $null   4   5   6   7   8   
Entry 2 $null   B   A   B   A   B   A   B
```

So I've managed to have the code 'ignore/skip' a null value within a set.

My output looks like this

```
Field1,1,2,4,5,6
Field2,1
Field1,B,A,B,A,B
Field2
```

What I would like help with now is how to either remove "Field2" because it has no value, or comment it out using ;.

So my output would look like

```
Field1,1,2,4,5,6
Field2,1
Field1,B,A,B,A,B
```

or

```
Field1,1,2,4,5,6
Field2,1
Field1,B,A,B,A,B
;Field2
```

Essentially, if a row has no data in any of it's fields that are being written for that line, it should be ignored.

Thanks SO MUCH for your help.

EDIT:

I've discovered I need to remove the comma "," between the {0},{1} and use a space instead. So I'm using

```
$field2 = $("{0} {1}" -f "Field 2", $_."Value1")
$field2 = $field2.Split(" ",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
if ( $field2.Count -le 1) { ";$field2" } else { $field2 -join "`t`t" }
```

Which works for 'most' of my fields.

However there are 'some' Fields and Values that have spaces in them.
Additionally there some values like "TEST TEXT"

So now I'm getting

```
Field1  3,B,A,B,A,B
Field       2       TEST        TEXT
```

Instead of (quotes for clarity)

```
"Field1"    3,B,A,B,A,B
"Field 2"   "TEST TEXT"
```

I'm happy to just use some kind of exception only for these few fields.
I've tried a few other things, but I end up breaking the IF statement, and it ;comments out fields with values, or doesn't ;comment out fields with no values.

Comment: So you just need a simple `If` statement? `If($_.Value1){$Field2.Split...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next code snippet could help:

```
### … … … ###
$Content | foreach-object{

    $field1 = $("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}" -f "Field1", $_."Value1", $_."Value2", $_."Value3", $_."Value4", $_."Value5", $_."Value6")
    $auxarr = $field1.Split(",",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
    if ( $auxarr.Count -le 1) { ";$auxarr" } else { $auxarr -join "," }

    $field2 = $("{0},{1}" -f "Field2", $_."Value1")
    $auxarr = $field2.Split(",",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
    if ( $auxarr.Count -le 1) { ";$auxarr" } else { $auxarr -join "," }

} | Out-File $OutFile
```

**Edit** to answer additional (extending) subquestion *I need to remove the comma "," between the `{0},{1}` and use a space instead*:

```
    $field2 = $("{0},{1}" -f "Field 2", $_."Value1")
    ### keep comma  ↑        ↓   or any other character not contained in data
    $field2 = $field2.Split(",",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
    if ( $field2.Count -le 1) { ";$field2" } else { $field2 -join "`t`t" }
```

If your data *contain* a *significant comma* then use [`Split(String(), StringSplitOptions)` form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) of `String.Split` Method e.g. as follows:

```
    $burstr = [string[]]'#-#-#'
    $field2 = $("{0}$burstr{1}" -f "Field 2", $_."Value1")
    $field2 = $field2.Split($burstr,[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
    if ( $field2.Count -le 1) { ";$field2" } else { $field2 -join "`t`t" }
```

Comment: Hey again JosefZ.
That works!

You rock! :)

I'm using $field1 & $field2 instead of $auxarr
It seems to work, but wanted to check if that is OK? or bad practice?

Just want to easily identify the variables for the particular field.
I could use $field1x or something instead if that's recommended?

Comment: I've updated the question with a problem I'm experiencing with how I needed to tweak the code.
Thanks again! (I feel it's closely related enough to warrant being part of the same question).